# "Finished running <application_name> on <device_name>" issue

Tags: ios5

I have a iPad 2 device with iOS version 5.0.1. I'm using Xcode 4.2 (for Snow Leopard). I've built my application with a deployment target for iOS 4.0 & the Base SDK is iOS 5.0.

The application is building successfully, but it is showing "Finished running  on " agter building successfully. But there is nothing installed in the device.

Is there anyone who can help me to get out of this issue ???

Any help is greatly appreciated...!!!!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your  info.plist and delete the Required device capabilities and reinstall the application